# Controller return LocalDateTime in JSON format in Micronaut controller

Tags: groovy, micronaut

Environmant:

- Micronaut: 3.7.3
- Java: OpenJDK 11.0.16
- Groovy: 3.0.13

My Controller is implemented with Groovy as below:

```
@Controller("/")
@Slf4j
class Controller1 {
    @Get(uri="/test-localdatetime", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    HttpResponse<String> testLocalDateTime() {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now()
        def map = [
                status: "SSUCCESS",
                time: now
        ]
        return HttpResponse.ok(map)
    }
}
```

When I call it, it returns:

```
{"status":"SSUCCESS","time":[2022,11,2,8,24,13,948454300]}
```

If I want it to return a beautified JSON as below, I could add below code

```
String json = new JsonBuilder(map).toPrettyString()
return HttpResponse.ok(json)
```

And the response will become (still not what I want):

```
{
    "status": "SSUCCESS",
    "time": {
        "month": "NOVEMBER",
        "second": 29,
        "hour": 8,
        "nano": 944749300,
        "year": 2022,
        "dayOfMonth": 2,
        "minute": 44,
        "monthValue": 11,
        "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
        "chronology": {
            "calendarType": "iso8601",
            "id": "ISO"
        },
        "dayOfYear": 306
    }
}
```

But the idea response I want is below format:

```
{
  "status":"SSUCCESS",
  "time":"2022-11-02 08:24:13"
}
```

So, I wonder if there is an easy way to reach the above idea format by just adding some configurations or annotations without changing the intial code ?

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle to show what you actually use at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure the jackson serialization yourself in the application.yml

```yaml
jackson:
   dateFormat: yyyyMMdd
   timeZone: UTC
   serialization:
     writeDatesAsTimestamps: false
```

By the way, I strongly recommend to use a `java.time.Instant` over `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Furthermore I would change the return type of your controller to return a `Map` instead of a `String` so the framework can care about serialising the `Map`, since you are returning a map and not a string.

```
@Controller("/")
@Slf4j
class Controller1 {
    @Get(uri="/test-localdatetime", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    HttpResponse<Map> testLocalDateTime() {
        def map = [
                status: "SUCCESS",
                time: Instant.now()
        ]
        return HttpResponse.ok(map)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just gave it a try but no luck.
Well, I use Groovy to implement the controller without using jackson lib. Does it matter ?

Comment: Well, the Jackson serialization is done by the framework using the return type of your controller method. Do you have Jackson on the classpath? You don't want to do the serialization in your controller.

Have you tried using a `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use date/time only on one place or you need to have different formats on different places then you can:

**Return DTO where you can set format by annotation**

Example DTO class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat
import java.time.LocalDateTime

class SomeResponse {
    String status
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    LocalDateTime time
}
```

Controller method:

```
@Get(uri="/test-localdatetime", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
SomeResponse testLocalDateTime() {
    new SomeResponse(
        status: "SSUCCESS",
        time: LocalDateTime.now()
    )
}
```

**Continue using Map but convert the time value manually**

Controller changes:

```
final static def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

@Get(uri="/test-localdatetime", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Map testLocalDateTime() {
    def now = LocalDateTime.now()
    [
        status: "SSUCCESS",
        time: formatter.format(now)
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if I wwant to apply to a query result from database and the entities contains LocalDateTime properties? I am afrais this could not be a good approach